# Getting "Failed to notify project evaluation listener" using Liberty Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

With a simple Open Liberty project like one generated using the starter website (https://start.openliberty.io/) I get the following error on `gradle build`:

```
$ gradle build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'app-name'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > groovy/lang/GroovyObject.getProperty(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

My **build.gradle** has this:

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'io.openliberty.tools.gradle.Liberty' version '3.6.2'
}
```

I'm using Gradle v6.9.1 and Java 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EXPLANATION

Starting with the Liberty Gradle plugin version 3.6, Gradle v7.3 or higher is [required](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.gradle/#usage).

You can either:

- downgrade the Liberty Gradle plugin version to v3.5.2
- **OR**, upgrade your Gradle version to v7.3+.

### SOLUTION

In the case where you already have a Gradle wrapper of an older version you might even need to do something like:

1. Downgrade the Liberty Gradle plugin version to v3.5.2
2. Generate a newer wrapper, e.g.:  `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=7.4.2`
3. Upgrade the Liberty Gradle plugin version (e.g. back to v3.6).

(You might need to do this because otherwise the `./gradlew wrapper` command will fail with the same, original error).